# WordPress WP JSON is not working after updating WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, apache2, razorpay

I have a WordPress website in which I am using WooCommerce as an e-commerce solution, and Razorpay as a payment solution, and also I have my own plugin which is using the rest route from WP JSON from my website. When I update WooCommerce from version 7.6.1 to version 7.7.2 then there is a critical error on the WP JSON request after debugging also I can't find any solution, I found that when I downgrade the WooCommerce version to 7.6.1 the WP JSON request starts working again. Also, there is one more scenario in which when I upgrade the WooCommerce Plugin to version 7.7.2 and when I deactivate the Razorpay plugin then also WP JSON requests are working properly.

I have also checked server logs and apache2 logs, but there is no log entered for this request there.

I want to upgrade the WooCommerce and also keep Razorpay plugin on my website.

If anyone has a solution, please help.

Comment: Have you enabled WP debug mode? Where exactly does the error show, _where_ do you see it say(?) "critical error"?

Comment: I have already enabled the WP debug mode and checked and when i use Ajax request from my plugin then it throws the 500 error or CORS error @CBroe

When I hit the URL yoursite.com/wp-json then it throws me an error after upgrading.

Comment: If you get a 500 Internal Server Error, then you should usually find something about it in the error log though. (Unless that status code was explicitly set by WP itself, but I don't think it does that.)

Comment: Please follow [the official WordPress instructions to enable debugging](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/), and report the error(s) here.

Comment: Check Plugin Compatibility: Make sure that all your installed plugins, including WooCommerce and any related extensions, are up to date and compatible with the latest version of WordPress. Incompatible or outdated plugins can cause conflicts that affect the WP JSON API.